# How to include C library (VLFeat 0.9.21) in iOS Project?

Tags: ios, c, vlfeat

What are the necessary steps I need to take to compile VLFeat (an open source C library) and include it in my iOS project? Here is what I found out so far:

I am not too familiar with the compilation and linking procedures, but from what I currently understand, I need to compile VLFeat for the arm64 architecture in order for it to run on the iPhone.

There is a severely outdate guide on how to include VLFeat in XCode:
http://www.vlfeat.org/xcode.html

But when I follow these steps I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_vl_get_printf_func", referenced from:
  -[OpenCVWrapper createMatrixFromImage:] in OpenCVWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I suspect this is because the library is actually built for OSX (hence for a different architecture). I have not been able to figure out how to build this for iOS (arm architecture) and get it running on a physical iPhone.

When I open the XCode project that is included in the VLFeat download and go to build settings for one of the Targets and change the `Base SDK` to iOS and `Supported platforms` to iOS and `Valid Architectures` to arm64 and then try to build, a bunch of errors come up for the VLFeat source code such as:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:64:12: Invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
```

and

```
"Compiling with SSE2 enabled, but no __SSE2__ defined"
```

These errors make me suspect that actually its not possible to build this library for arm and that, short of porting the library over (modifying code), it is an impossible task. I am not sure whether the conclusions I reached are correct so any input on this would be helpful.

Comment: SSE is an Intel technology that is not available on the iOS devices' ARM chips. Does this lib support ios?

Answer (score 0):

The [VLFeat library](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat) does not currently (January 2023) support ARM architectures, and seems to no longer be maintained, as the last commit was in January 2018.

However, [this commit](https://github.com/ojwoodford/ojwul/commit/993ccd29ca5688e3f21db179cc4483591127af48) to a copy of the library updates the host.h and host.c files to add basic support for the Clang compiler and ARM architectures. This has enabled me to compile binaries for the Apple M1 Pro processor running MacOS, and these perform as expected.

Performance will not be as good as on Intel CPUs because the SIMD Neon instruction set for ARM is not yet supported, whereas SSE2 (on Intel) is.